# Reference a specific cell in excel; values will change when rows are added

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

Help is appreciated on this issue, thanks!

How can I reference a specific cell from Sheet1 onto Sheet2? The catch is, if I add new rows above row 1, I want Sheet2 to continue referencing the new values in A1. Not the values of A1 that were moved to A2, A3, etc when new rows were added.

I have taken excel courses before but this is my first workbook projectwhere I am applying concepts.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Index:

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!A:A,1)
```

Now even if rows are added or deleted it will always refer to the first row in Column A.

Comment: Thank you! I also found
`=INDIRECT("Sheet1!A1")`
to work. Good to have multiple methods.

Comment: @SubwayMusicNYC be careful with INDIRECT as it is volatile and will slow the calculations of excel down if it is used too much.  Index is not volatile and why I suggested it.  If my answer works, please mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate the function comparisons